# HTML disabled textarea but still resizable

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you disable a textarea, it doesn't let you type or resize it. I would like to be able to resize it, just not type in it.
Javascript solutions ok but not prefered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add property `readonly` to the field and CSS background color and text color:

```css
.my-disabled{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="my-disabled" name=area1 readonly>Text goes here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by default resize a disabled textarea, perhaps you are using a library that overwrites is. You can see it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5wdxc62/

Code in fiddle is very simple, just plain html

```
<textarea disabled></textarea>
```

Comment: Huh you're right that does work. My html has two textareas: one disabled and one not, and my css is: `textarea { resize: vertical; }` but I can only resize the non-disabled one.
EDIT: Works fine in firefox, my problem is in chrome, but your example works fine in chrome.

Comment: When I tried that (in chrome) it still lets me resize, but as expected, only vertically. It might be an issue with an older version of chrome, or you may have other rules being applied that you aren't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

make text area read only

```
<textarea name="largetext" readonly></textarea>
```